# Erro a carregar um arquivo HTML

Tags: jquery, html5

Bom , alguns dias fiz uma pergunta sobre otimização aqui , e obtive respostas satisfatórias. Logo cheguei a conclusão , que o modo que eu estava fazendo o meu sistema WEB iria causar problemas de desempenho , pois estava fazendo todas as minhas telas e formulários dentro de um unico index, a solução que pensei foi separar as telas e criar um arquivo html para cada uma, de forma que esse arquivo só é lido quando o usuario clica para abrir determinada tela. Fiz um codigo e funcionou , só que estou tendo um erro no arquivo do `jquery` e o erro está variando, muito estranho.

Hora recebo esse erro:
`jquery.js:1451 Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function`

E depois , esse:

`jquery.js:1451 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Esse é o codigo

```
$LAB.script('formularios/prospeccao/prospeccao.js').wait();
$.post('formularios/prospeccao/prospeccao.html', function(html) {
    $('#formulario_geral_prospeccao_id').html(html);
});
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o porquê desse erro ? Obrigado!

Comment: que tipo de elemento é o 'formulario_geral_prospeccao_id' ?

Comment: É um ```section```, ai dentro dele eu carrego o conteúdo HTML da minha tela.

Comment: Tem alguma variável 'a' no seu código? Eu já tive um problema assim quando ia selecionar um link e chamar o método `click`, não lembro a versão do jQuery, mas resolvi usando um índice, mesmo o elemento sendo selecionado por id. No seu código, seria algo como  `$('#formulario_geral_prospeccao_id')[0].html(html)`

Comment: Entendi. Não funcionou para mim dessa maneira, porque o ```$('#formulario_geral_prospeccao_id').html(html)``` é o elemeno que vai receber o conteudo html. Reparei uma coisa , parece que o erro fica variando , recebi esse erro agora ```jquery.js:1451 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function```. O mais engraçado é que quando eu fazia tudo direto no mesmo index rolava sem nenhum problema.